# Where Should I Install Galera Load Balancer? On Cluster Nodes?

Tags: replication, mariadb, clustering, ubuntu, galera

I want to install Galera Load Balancer for my 3-Node Galera Cluster, but where should I install the galera load balancer? Can I install on the cluster nodes or should I build a new server for galera load balancer?

Comment: Put it on each.

Comment: @RickJames can you explain me what is the logic on this? I have built HAProxy and it was on a server without databases?

Comment: That's fine until that one server crashes.  Logic:  to avoid a "single-point-of-failure", namely the only server that _everything_ uses, namely HAProxy.

Comment: @RickJames so you suggest to install galera load balancer on every node and use it as the load balancer, did I understand well?